# How to register dependency injection with generic types? (.net core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an asp.net core web app with multiple parameters in appSettings.json file.

I didnt' want to have services having `IOptions<MyObject>` in the constructor.

I wanted MyObject in the constructor.
So I found the following article: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/dec/12/easy-configuration-binding-in-aspnet-core-revisited which is very interesting.

But I want to go further. I would like to create an extension method to generate the injection.

Here is what I would like to do:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Common.WebTools.Extensions
{
    public static class IServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddSingletonConfigurationObject<T>(this IServiceCollection services, 
            IConfiguration configuration,
            string appSettingsKey) where T:new()
        {   
            var obj2 = new T();
            configuration.Bind(appSettingsKey, obj);
            services.AddSingleton(obj2); //compilation failed
            return services;
        }
    }
}
```

And then in my ConfigureServices method I can call

```cs
services.AddSingletonConfigurationObject<Common.Tools.Configuration.GoogleAnalyticsConfiguration>(Configuration, "GoogleAnalytics");
```

But I Have a compliation error on this line:

```cs
services.AddSingleton(obj2);
```

Does somebody know how could I correct the error?

Comment: And what does the error says?

Comment: impossible cast from 'T' to 'System.Type'
->it doesn't use the good constructor

Comment: I am not sure but maybe it can't guess the type. Alternatively you can try ```serices.AddSingleton<T>(obj2)``` or ```services.AddSingleton(typeof(T), obj2)```

Comment: And T shoud be defined as class: ```where T : class, new()```

Comment: Thank you @Rabban
   where T : class, new()
is the key :)

Answer (score 83):

You can use services.AddScoped to use only 1 instance in the scope request. So in general improvement compare to AddTransient

```cs
services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
```

So my interface and class will look like this

```cs
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
```

```cs
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
```

Comment: So how would the target for the injected instance actually look?

Comment: Is it even possible with constructor injecton since it requires a type argument?
private readonly IGenericRepository<???> _repository;

Comment: private readonly IGenericRepository<T> GenericRepository; ....... in the constructor parameters use ....IGenericRepository<T> genericRepository; and in body of constructor set the property .... GenericRepository = genericRepository. you have to use it in generic class, with same T inheritance.

Comment: Any idea why this idea can't work with `AddTransient`?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments you should set the generic constraint to `where T: class` in order to satisfy the constraint of the `AddSingleton` call.

Reference [AddSingleton(IServiceCollection, TService)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddSingleton__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection___0_)

Additionally you can bind the object graph using `ConfigurationBinder.Get<T>`

Reference [Configuration in ASP.NET Core : Bind to an object graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#bind-to-an-object-graph)

> `ConfigurationBinder.Get<T>` binds and returns the specified type. `Get<T>` is more convenient than using `Bind`.

like in the following example

```
public static class IServiceCollectionExtensions {
    public static IServiceCollection AddSingletonConfigurationObject<TService>(
        this IServiceCollection services, 
        IConfiguration configuration,
        string appSettingsKey) where TService: class
    {   

        var setting = configuration.GetSection(appSettingsKey).Get<TService>();
        services.AddSingleton(setting);
        return services;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use this style to encapsulate (as an extension method)

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;

namespace MyProject.DependencyInjection
{
    public static class MyEncapsulatedIocRegistration
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddTypeT<T>(this IServiceCollection services) where T : class
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IMyThingInterface<T>, MyThingConcrete<T>>();

            return services;
        }
    }
}
```