# How to use AddTransient without knowing the exact generics

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

How would I go about rewriting something like the code below to a call to `services.AddTransient<IPipelineBehavior<?, ?>, ValidationBehaviour<?, ?>>`?

```cs
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(ValidationBehavior<,>));
```

It's probably something really simple, but I can't wrap my head around it. I've tried stuff like `services.AddTransient<IPipelineBehavior<_, _>, ValidationBehaviour<_, _>>` but the compiler wasn't having it. Is this even possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to register dependency injection with generic types? (.net core)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56271832/how-to-register-dependency-injection-with-generic-types-net-core)

Comment: Not really, I think. Basically, I want to get rid of the `typeof` operators and "just" use generics. Without knowing what those generics are, if that makes sense...