# Is this possible to register generic class, that has many variations, with MS DI?

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection

I have obsolete application with such class as

```
public class ServiceResult<T>
{
    private long _insertedEntityId;
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public List<T> Errors { get; set; }

    public long InsertedEntityId
    {
        get => _insertedEntityId;
        set
        {
            if (_insertedEntityId == 0)
                _insertedEntityId = value;
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("Value was set before");
        }
    }

    public bool HasErrors { get; set; }

    public void AddError(ClientBalanceServiceErrors clientBalanceServiceErrors, params T[] errorCodes)
    {
        foreach (var errorCode in errorCodes)
        {
            if (!Errors.Contains(errorCode))
                Errors.Add(errorCode);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this class injected in many other classes with different classes instead of T.

And when I run my application, I have mistakes, that service could not find instance of such generic as registered.

The problem is there are 100+ variations of such generic class in this application.

So, that is way I do not want to register files manually and want to register them with reflection.

Is this possible?

I try to adapt this sample code for my case - but was not succeed.
And I hope, I need not to refactor all cases and need not to add interface.

```
var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                        .GetAssemblies()
                        .SingleOrDefault(x => x.GetName().Name == "BusinessLogic.Services");

var commandServices = assembly?.GetTypes()
            .Where(a => a.Name.EndsWith("CommandService") && !a.IsAbstract && !a.IsInterface)
            .Select(a => new { assignedType = a, serviceTypes = a.GetInterfaces().ToList() })
            .ToList();
```

Also, when I try to use advice from comments section, I have such notifications.

[image]

Comment: What is "MS DI"? Common DI containers allow registering services with unresolved generics but i have no idea where you are.

Comment: This is microsoft dependency injection approach to register application instances in a composition root.

Comment: My current approach now I want to avoid with reflection is:
services.AddTransient<ServiceResult<ClientRequisitesServiceErrors>>();
services.AddTransient<ServiceResult<DomainXrrpQueueServiceErrors>>();
services.AddTransient <ServiceResult <RequisitesVerificationServiceErrors>>();
services.AddTransient <ServiceResult <ClientBalanceServiceErrors>>();
services.AddTransient <ServiceResult <DomainRegistryServiceErrors>>();
services.AddTransient <ServiceResult <DomainServiceErrors>>();

Comment: Just `services.AddTransient<ServiceResult<>>` ?

Comment: No, but you gave me an idea:
services.AddTransient<ServiceResult<object>>();
I am not sure, but I think this could work.

Comment: What i showed should work for the standard ASP.Net core DI Container. I'm pretty sure registering it with "object" works with no DI Container.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to register dependency injection with generic types? (.net core)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56271832/how-to-register-dependency-injection-with-generic-types-net-core)

Comment: `services.AddTransient(typeof(ServiceResult<>));`

Comment: Thanks, Ralf!

How to register dependency injection with generic types? (.net core)
I would not say, but somehow remotely at first glance, although the name of the topic is similar.