# Dependency Injection with Generic Interface

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to inject a class containing a generic method using a generic interface. Schematically, this would look something like

```
public interface IInterface<T>
{
    public List<ClassC<T>> Method(List<ClassC<T>> list);
}

public class ClassA : IInterface<ClassB>
{
    List<ClassC<ClassB>> inList = ...;
    List<ClassC<ClassB>> outList = Method(List < ClassC < ClassB >> inList);
    {
        return inList;
    }
}
```

and in Startup.cs I have

```
public delegate IInterface<T> Resolver(Type key);

builder.Services.AddTransient<Resolver>(serviceProvider => key =>
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case ClassB:
            return serviceProvider.GetService<ClassA>();
        default:
            throw new Exception;
    }
});
```

However this does not work as C# does not know what  is on runtime when running Startup.cs. My aim is to be able to use different definitions of the generic method Method() in different controllers. Is there a way to achieve this using dependency injection or by any other means?

Comment: Is `ClassA` registered in the DI container?

Comment: Does [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56271832/how-to-register-dependency-injection-with-generic-types-net-core) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work fine:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IInterface<ClassB>, ClassA>();
```

And then you can inject the following into a class:

```
public SomeClass(IInterface<ClassB> classBInterface) { ... }
```

And it's concrete type, if you inspect, will indeed by `ClassA`